# Lock Screen With Ads on Samsung Galaxy S5 mini

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-5-mini

i've got lock screen, I do not know how I got into the phone, and I do not even know how to fix it, is it a virus? please answer, phone isn't rooted

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Quickest and the most painful way would be to do a factory reset. Sure, you can try different malware removal options, but that would probably take a lot longer than to just re-setup your phone. Connect your phone to your PC, take you important files that you need, scan them with anti-malware, factory reset your phone, add files back in and check whats up.

In theory, if you really want to avoid resetting, you can try the following. Disconnect your phone from the internet if possible, if not, just turn off your router for a little bit, restart your phone, see if the screen-lock is there. See if you can access running processes, most screen-locks are pretty dumb and will still allow you to get to plenty of functions.